# wake up from suspend via keyboard in Debian 12

Tags: debian, suspend

With bullseye this line in /etc/rc.local worked:

echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/

... to enable a keypress to wake up the system from suspend. Doesn't work in bookworm. These other efforts were suggested: (hopefully adding resume via mouse as well as keyboard):

echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/5-2/power/wakeup
echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/8-1/power/wakeup

... or:

echo enabled > /sys/class/usbmisc/hiddev0/power/wakeup
echo enabled > /sys/class/usbmisc/hiddev1/power/wakeup

... but nothing works. Is this functionality still available?  I see this question has been asked many times over the years, but the proposed solutions seem to vary all over the place.  What's this week's solution?

Answer (score 0):

Glorious success:

https://www.makeuseof.com/wake-your-lin … b-devices/

... they've just made it a wee bit harder, like they do:

```
echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/5-2/power/wakeup
echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/8-1/power/wakeup
echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb5/power/wakeup
echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb8/power/wakeup
```

... seems you now have to wake up the port *and* the device on the port.